# Rails rspec maxes out CPU and does not complete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm working on a ruby on rails project with a team. Locally, only for me, `rspec spec/path/to/file.rb` maxes the CPU and does not start working on the test file. The same test run by a colleague ran and completed in around 30 seconds. Everything else seems to be working as expected locally. My `node`, `npm`, `rails`, `ruby`, `bundler` versions match my colleagues.

```
MacOS 11.6.1
node 15.14.0
npm 7.7.6
Ruby 2.5.6
Rails 5.2.5
bundler 1.16.2
```

Are there any other packages that I need to look to update / downgrade? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had to do with the project expecting a different time zone. Switching my computer to the expected time zone fixed `rspec` from hanging.